# Unable to create files via Bash

Tags: bash, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using the Azure App Service Kudu Shell to create a file called applicationHost.xdt. Since I am unable to upload the file, I am using the following chained shell command to generate it:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" > applicationHost.xdt && echo "<configuration xmlns:xdt=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform\"> " >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "  <system.webServer>" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "    <runtime xdt:Transform=\"InsertIfMissing\">" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform=\"InsertIfMissing\">" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "        <add name=\"FOO\" value=\"BAR\" xdt:Locator=\"Match(name)\" xdt:Transform=\"InsertIfMissing\" />" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "        <add name=\"PATH\" value=\"%PATH%;%HOME%\BAR\" xdt:Locator=\"Match(name)\" xdt:Transform=\"InsertIfMissing\" />" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "      </environmentVariables>" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "    </runtime>" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "  </system.webServer>" >> applicationHost.xdt && echo "</configuration>" >> applicationHost.xdt
```

Essentially, just writing the file line by line with echo commands. This works fine locally on both bash and zsh.

After running

```
echo "${BASH_VERSION}"
```

On the terminal, I get the response "4.4.12(1)-release". I am not sure if the version is incorrect. The error message I am getting from the shell (when running the full command) is:

```
version="1.0"?> > applicationHost.xdt && echo <configuration: ?xml: No such file or directory
```

When I try and run the first part of the command (echo "" > applicationHost.xdt), I get the message:

```
version="1.0"?> > applicationHost.xdt && echo '' && pwd: ?xml: No such file or directory
```

I think this has something to do with the quotations / the program not recognising escape characters, but other than that I am not sure.

Comment: The code shown here looks fine. Are you *sure* you are using `bash`? The problem appears to be that the `"` is being ignored or treated literally, so that the following `<` is treated as a redirection operator, with `?xml` being the file you are attempting to read from.

Comment: The error message makes it look like you are running something like `"version=\"1.0\"?> > applicationHost.xdt && echo <configuration" < ?xml`.

Comment: Thank you.
Upon shell startup:
`Kudu Remote Execution Console`
`Type 'exit' to reset this console.`
`/home>echo "$SHELL`
`/bin/sh`
I did further research and I think it might be the Bourne shell. Is the file creation process different?

Comment: No, I think the problem involves the way your script gets executed, which isn't shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using single quotes solves the problem:

```
echo '<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>' > applicationHost.xdt
```

I have no real idea why this works, as the shell seems to be either bash or Bourne sh.

Comment: I wonder how, exactly, your script gets executed. I'm starting to suspect some sort of `eval` issue, where your first `"` is interpreted as closing some previous `"`, rather than being part of your own script. I'm picturing something like `eval sh -c '"$YOURSCRIPT"'`

Answer (score 0):

Not really relevant to your actual problem (which I suspect is due to something out of your control, or due to something you aren't showing in your question), but a simpler way to create this file would be with a here document:

```
cat <<'EOF' > applicationHost.xdt
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="FOO" value="BAR" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\BAR" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
EOF
```

(It *might* fix your problem incidentally, as the quoting changes.)